# Do I need to ask for cookie consent in app web view using mobile specific website?

Tags: android, ios, cookies, webview, android-webview

If I have an app consisting of a WebView that displays a web page made exclusively for mobile.

When navigating to the site an ugly un-immersive popup shows making the otherwise app designed website look like a normal browser page.

Can I remove this cookie consent notification and just state somewhere that using the app gives us consent to store cookies?

If not, what is the best way to make it a seamless integration?

Comment: in andorid or iOS ?

Comment: Both.
Currently building in Flutter.